# Problem "Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl."

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, daemon

## I want to build android app by command 'react-native run-android' and get FAILURE

**The App is building but in the end, I got this in command console**

I`ve already rebuilded app, restarted PC and Android device, deleted node_modueles folder but nothing helped me.

D:\Projects\Android\Partymaker>react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Projects\Android\Partymaker\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 95
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 0s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug

Comment: Plz post your `package.json`  file content

Comment: What version of RN?

Comment: RN version - "react-native": "0.59.3"

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/5N0kXl) **-** _package.json_

Comment: This edit in android/build.gradle will fix the depreciated warnings...
`-task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {`
`+wrapper {`
`gradleVersion = '4.4' `
`-    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")`
`+    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL`
` }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I was able to resolve it like this:

#### Fix gradle deprecation warnings by editing android/build.gradle

```
- task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
+ wrapper {
     gradleVersion = '4.4'
-    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
+    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
  }
```

#### Update classpath in android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependancies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
  }
}
```

#### update distributionUrl for android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

#### re-install node_modules

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn
```

I should mention that I still have other build errors from some custom libraries which I haven't resolved yet. But hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

this issue because of mismatch react-native version 
I assume you was on expo then you eject to react native 
try to remove node_modules 
change package.json react native version to 0.57.*
then react-native run-android